# How to display the new order of the parent after sorting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here are my current codes. These codes sort both parent and child but it display only the new order of the child after sorting.

**template**

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul id="envelopes" class="dropcat cat-data">
        <li id="1">
            <span class="cat-title">Utilities</span>
            <ul class="dropenv mt">
                <li class="innerList">Electricity</li>
                <li class="innerList">Water</li>
                <li class="innerList">Trash</li>
                <li class="innerList">Television</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="2">
            <span class="cat-title">Sample</span>
            <ul class="dropenv mt">
                <li class="innerList">Test</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="3">
            <span class="cat-title">Saving</span>
            <ul class="dropenv mt">
                <li class="innerList">College Fund</li>
                <li class="innerList">Retirement Fund</li>
                <li class="innerList">Emergency Fund</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p id="cl"></p>
```

**js**

```
<script>
    var addPositions = function() {
        $('.dropenv, .dropcat').each(function() {
            var position = 0;
            $(this).children().each(function() {
                $(this).data('position', position);
                position++;
            });
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        addPositions();
        var origTitle;
        var origColor;
        $(".dropenv").sortable({
            connectWith: "ul.mt",
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            start: function(event, ui) {
                origColor = ui.item.text();
                origTitle = ui.item.parent().siblings('.cat-title').text();
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                var order = [];

                ui.item.closest('ul').children('li').each(function() {
                    order.push($(this).data('position'));
                    var c = $(this).text();
                    if (c === origColor) {
                        var z = origTitle;
                    } else {
                        var z = $(this).parent().siblings('.cat-title').text();
                    }
                    $("#cl").append(z + "_" + c + "<br /\>");
                });
            }
        });

        $( "ul.dropcat").sortable({
            connectWith: "ul.cat-data",
            dropOnEmpty: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

**How to get the new order of the parent?**

For example:

```
   Before:
      - Utilities
      - Sample
      - Saving

  //If I'm going to swap Saving to Utilities, it must be display the new order like this

   New Order:
      - Saving
      - Sample
      - Utilities
```

**Update from @Jack Shedd**

I copy the `stop` and I get this output:

```
_ Utilities Electricity Water Natural Gas Home Phone Cell Phones Trash Television Internet
_ Charity/Giving Charitable Gifts Fast Offerings
_ Sample test
_ Recreation Entertainment Vacation
_ Saving College Fund Emergency Fund Retirement Fund
```

How to get parent only, no child?

Comment: When do you want do get the parent position? Are you saying drag and drop works for the children, but not for the parent?

Comment: @JackShedd they are both working fine in drag and drop. My problem is when I drag the parent I can't display the new order of the parent. But when I drag the child, I can display the new order of the child.

Comment: When you say display the order, are you talking ing that #cl tag you're updating within `stop` event of your sortable?

Comment: I want to display the new order of the parent position if I drag the parent.

Comment: @JackShedd yes in the #cl tag, it will append (display) the new order

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code and the question:

1. You have a custom `stop` event handler on your `sortable` object which, after the user stops dragging, will append the new position of the child to the innerHTML of the #cl paragraph tag.
2. You're wondering why this works for the children, but not the parent.

If you look at your jQuery, you'll see this line:

```
$(".dropenv").sortable({
```

This is applying the `sortable` behavior to any element with a class of `.dropenv`. It's here that you're initing the custom `stop` event handler which updates the #cl tag.

However, you're only applying this behavior to elements with a class of `.dropenv`, which, reviewing your html for the parent:

```
<ul id="envelopes" class="dropcat cat-data">
```

The parent UL doesn't match.

Instead, you're applying an entirely new `sortable` behavior to the parent:

```
    $( "ul.dropcat").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul.cat-data",
        dropOnEmpty: true,
    });
```

Which has none of the custom `stop` handler code contained within it.

So either copy the `stop` handler code from the `.dropenv` sortable options into the one above, or make the `.dropenv` sortable apply to your `.dropcat` UL as well.

Comment: I copy the `stop` and I get an output now. But the output has a child data. How to get only parent?

Comment: Change `ui.item.closest('ul').children('li').each` to just `ui.item.each`, I think.

Comment: I only got one parent with the child `_ Charity/Giving Charitable Gifts Fast Offerings`

Comment: Ah. Try `ui.item.children('ul')`.

Comment: Actually, my first bit should have worked. If you `console.log(ui.item)`, what's it say?

Comment: None... I think we are near in the exact answer. Maybe I need to add or remove something here