# How to get the parent id when the child is sort

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is related to this: [How to display the new order of the parent after sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425213/how-to-display-the-new-order-of-the-parent-after-sorting)

I already solved the above question. Now is I want to get the parent id when the child is sort.

Example: When I swap Water to Electricity,

```
         <li id="1">
            <span class="cat-title">Utilities</span>
            <ul class="dropenv mt">
                <li class="innerList">Electricity</li>
                <li class="innerList">Water</li>
                <li class="innerList">Trash</li>
                <li class="innerList">Television</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
```

the output must be,

```
   1_Electricity
   1_Water
   1_Trash
   1_Television
```

because 1 is the id of Utilities

**Here are the codes:**

```
 [.............]
        var parentID;
        var origColor;
        $(".dropenv").sortable({
            connectWith: "ul.env-data",
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            start: function(event, ui) {
                origColor = ui.item.text();

                //this is the id that produce undefined value
                parentID = ui.item.parent().siblings('li').attr('id');
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                var order = [];

                ui.item.closest('ul').children('li').each(function() {
                    order.push($(this).data('position'));
                    var c = $(this).text();
                    var z = parentID;
                    //if (c === origColor) {
                    //    var z = origTitle;
                    //} else {
                    //    var z = $(this).parent().siblings('.cat-title').text();
                    //}
                    $("#cl").append(z + "_" + c + "<br /\>");
                });
            }
        });

[.............]
```

The above codes produce undefined value:

```
   undefined_Electricity
   undefined_Water
   undefined_Trash
   undefined_Television
```

How to get the exact parent id?

Comment: I don't really see how django is related here

Comment: I'm not saying it's not connected to the linked question. I'm saying it shouldn't be tagged as `django`

Comment: @DJV Sorry I just tag it because I'm using Django.

Comment: what is `#cl`? I see the erroneous output. but what is expected output and where it should be shown?

Comment: @HungryCoder `#cl`, this is where the new order append and display it on the template. I put the example output in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
parentID = ui.item.closest('li[id]').attr('id');
```

Another complete solution

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul.env-data",
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var parentId = ui.item.parent().closest('li').attr('id');
        // Or this
        //var parentId = ui.item.closest('li[id]').attr('id');
        ui.item.closest('ul').children('li').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var text = $this.data('text');
            if(!text){
                text = $this.text();
                $this.data('text', text);
            }
            $this.text(parentId + '_' + text)
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ygG8u/4/)

Comment: @catherine: Uhm, it can't be. `ui.item.closest('li')` gives you the element itself.

Comment: @zeroflagL yeah but because he put `attr('id')`, the output will be the `id number`

Comment: @catherine: Sure, but the element has no id, that's the point. You need the parent to get the id. Whatever you did, [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/LG74w/) does not work.

Comment: @zeroflagL it's perfectly working on me. I will not accept his answer if not. I put sample codes above `<li id="1">`.

Comment: @zeroflagL ok I got your point. It's not working on you because it's not the complete codes. I will try to update your fiddle.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: The working fiddle is different from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

your item here is `<ul class="dropenv mt">`.. go to `parent(li)` and get the `id`.. no need of `sibling()`;

try this

```
var parentID ="";
parentID = ui.item.parent('li').attr('id');
```

Comment: Same with @Ravi, the output is undefined

Answer (score 0):

initilize parentID with default value. 
 `var parentID ='';`

then search for the parent.

```
 parentID = ui.item.parent().parent('li').attr('id');
```

Comment: The output is still undefined

Comment: @Ravi: `parent('li')` is the same as `parent()` in this case. There is no need for a selector.